# word meaning "agriculture encyclopedia"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that means "agriculture encyclopedia"; a book about farming. Does such a word exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single word, but along the lines suggested by @DianeEngelstad, how about **agronomy handbook**? From M-W:

> **[agronomy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agronomy)**: a branch of agriculture dealing with field-crop production and soil management

An example:

> The **[Agronomy Handbook](https://midwestlabs.com/resource/agronomy-handbook/)** is a comprehensive resource that discusses soil properties, plant essential nutrients, soil test results, and recommendations. Agriculture-related analyses are indispensable in supplying accurate, current information for making management decisions regarding soil fertility and plant nutrients.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word for an encyclopedic book on farming. Are you thinking about the Farmer's Almanac? Or perhaps a "Farmer's Handbook" is closer to what you are looking for? There are lots of Encyclopedias on farming as well.